# Unable to install php7.1-bcmath on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-7.1, ubuntu-17.10

I am trying to install a laravel package name [bitwasp](https://packagist.org/packages/bitwasp/bitcoin) but in this there is requirement of bcmath . when ever i tried to install it gave me error overe bcmath ,So i tried to install bcmath via this command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-bcmath
```

but when ever i do this got error also my Ubuntu is 17.10 and this is the error i got

```
After this operation, 128 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-gd amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-bz2 amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-opcache amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-json amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-mcrypt amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-zip amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-curl amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-xml amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-mbstring amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-mysql amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-readline amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php7.1 amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-cli amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-common amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
Err:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu artful/main amd64 php7.1-bcmath amd64 7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-gd_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-bz2_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-opcache_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-json_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-mcrypt_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-zip_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-curl_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-xml_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-mbstring_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-mysql_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-readline_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/libapache2-mod-php7.1_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-cli_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-common_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.1/php7.1-bcmath_7.1.12-2+ubuntu17.10.1+deb.sury.org+2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

already run update and fix-missing nothing happen every time got same error

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt update
apt install php7.1-bcmath
```

Restart apache and all good to go.

Comment: wait i'll try this and let you know, btw thnks

Comment: care to explain what's error is , how do i prevent from this kind of errors